# What does it mean to reverse time?

Tags: time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

Experiments are done to see if a process is symmetric (or asymmetric) with respect to the reversal of time. So if a process happens if the particles move in one direction, but not the other way round if you reverse the velocities of the particles participating in the process (after the process) the other way around it is asymmetric with respect to time reversal. Does this mean that time is reversed locally by giving the velocities of the particles after the process an opposite direction, while the velocities of all the other particles in the Universe stay the same (the clock in the lab runs forward)? **Is** time (locally or globally) reversed if you give all the particles velocities the opposite direction (disregarding for the moment the collapse or development of the wave functions or the expansion of the Universe? Would the locally changed velocities of the above-described process will still be asymmetric in time if you give **all** particles an opposite velocity?