# Is the reversal of the movement of all particles in phase-space, the expansion of space and the development of quantumfields equal to time reversal?

Tags: time, field-theory, space, phase-space

In an earlier [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334932/what-does-it-mean-to-reverse-time), which was called a duplicate, I already asked a similar question. But I state my question differently now and add something to it.

Suppose "we" would reverse the direction of the motion  of all elementary particles in the universe through [phase-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space), reverse the expansion of space (so **not** of space**time** for an obvious reason) as well as the development of all [quantum fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) associated with all the elementary particles in phase-space (so the particles are in fact not represented by points moving through phase-space, if we consider elementary particles as point-particles).

Does "doing" all these things (performing operations) amount to the reversal of time (somewhat like showing a film backward)? I know these operations differ from the time-reversal operator in QFT. I mean, doesn't the last one apply only to tiny parts of the universe (and certainly not to the **entire** wavefunction of the universe)? See for example [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_does_time-reversal_symmetry_mean_to_a_physical_system_say_a_system_described_by_a_partial_differential_equation).

Comment: Maybe. "CPT-invariance" deals (among charge and parity) with time-reversal but what is meant by time reversal in CPT-invariance? It's defined by a time reversal operator so I don't think it is seen as I ask in my question. The operator certainly doesn't perform the operations I suggest.

Comment: "as well as the development of all quantum fields", quantum field theory workd with CPT theorem and lorenz invariance. If your fantasy model has quantum fields, the answer is no.

Comment: Why? You can also reverse (in your imagination) the evolution of the wavefunction of one particle (in the position representation, the wave function would evolve to a wave function spreading out less and less), so why not that of a whole field of particles?